# Angularx-social-login - problem with redirect_uti, spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, google-signin, angular-social-login

I have the question regarding to redirect uri.

Using: angularx-social-login and spring boot in backend.

I added it to angular configuration file:

```
const googleLoginOptions: LoginOpt = {
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect'
}

const config = new AuthServiceConfig([
    {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider('XXX_Key', googleLoginOptions)
    },
]);
```

And that same redirect uri I put into yaml file on backend. With another library - f.e. react social login - it is working properly. With angular - I have positive feedback from google but redirect is not working.

Anybody has a similar issue?

Comment: I have similar problem in my application. Did you check config in dev google tools? I know, it is not big help. But maybe there is the some wrong config.

Comment: Yeah. Without any success. I am thinking about debugging. There is any solution to check if redirect is working via angularx-social-login library?